# Unrecognized tokens

Tags: unix, token, cat

What does this command do?

```
< cit cat - cot > cit
```

What do I have to do to make the command work? And I only know cat, can anybody tell me what cit and cot are?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what a command does how can you ask `What do I have to do to make the command work`. What do you actually want to do?

---

**Demo:**

Both `cit` and `cot` aren't not commands they are files.

```
$ cat cit
This is cit

$ cat cot
This is cot
```

The command:

```
$ < cit cat - cot
This is cit
This is cot
```

Is just a strange way of doing:

```
$ cat cit cot 
This is cit
This is cot
```

The `>` is a redirection operator that redirects the output of `cat` into `cit` but this will have an unexpected results as you are writing to a file you are reading from:

```
$ cat cit
This is cot
```

See the original content of `cit` is lost and only the contents of `cot` is written. `cot` is unaffected:

```
$ cat cot
This is cot
```

If this is desired behavior you should look at the copy command `cp`:

```
$ cp cot cit
```

If the desired behavior was concatenation of `cit` and `cot` then you need to use a temporary file to avoid [clobbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering):

```
$ cat cit cot > tmp
$ mv tmp cit
```

You could also do this using the logical and operator `&&`:

```
$ cat cit cot > tmp && mv tmp cit
```

Comment: My instructor just gave us this to ponder over over the weekend and I guess I didn't catch what was the end result that he wanted. But I ran these commands and hopefully its what he wanted. Thanks a lot for the help man!

Comment: @JurgenMalina okay so you should look into the following topics: **Redirection**, **Clobbering**, **Standard Streams**. Also you need to upvote an [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)!